# Arduino IDE with ATtiny85 error "multiple definition of `__vector_5"

Tags: timers, attiny, isr, attiny85

I am having a problem compiling the code for my ATtiny85 circuit.

I am using the timer/counter0 in normal mode so that when it overflows it triggers the TIMER0_OVF_vect ISR. When I have that ISR in my code, it wont compile and gives this error:

```
wiring.c.o (symbol from plugin): In function `__vector_5':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__vector_5'
sketch\Glove_heater_v1.ino.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1
Error compiling for board ATtiny25/45/85.
```

### Maybe I just need to use a different name for the ISR?

```
My Code:

//Red LED on PB0
//Blue LED on PB1
//Pushbutton PB2
//Battery voltage divider PB3
//Mosfet control PB4

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

volatile uint8_t checkVoltage = 0;

void setup() {

   DDRB = 0b0010011; //set PB0,PB1,PB4 as output, PB2,PB3 as input
   PORTB = 0b00000011; //set PB0,PB1 HIGH so LEDs are off, other pins LOW

   //Setup TC0 for overflow interrupt trigger
   TCCR0B |= 0b00000101; //clk/1024 prescaler
   TIMSK |= 0b00000010;  //set TOIE0 enable overflow interrupt
   sei();
}

void loop() { //do nothing in this test code

}

ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect){ //Timer/counter0 interrupt check voltage
   checkVoltage = 1;
}
```

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Arduino uses it for counting millis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message was:

> wiring.c.o [...]: multiple definition of `__vector_5'
>   Glove_heater_v1.ino.cpp.o [...]: first defined here

`__vector_5` is `TIMER0_OVF_vect`. So you have one definition of this
ISR in your sketch, and another one in wiring.c. This wiring.c is part
of the Arduino core. As KIIV puts it in a comment, it uses
`TIMER0_OVF_vect` for timekeeping (`millis()`, `micros()` and
`delay()`).

You have two options for solving this:

- you can use the other timer (Timer 1) in your sketch, and leave Timer
  0 for the Arduino core
- since you are not using the Arduino core anyway, you can get rid of it
  by simply defining `main()` in your sketch instead of `setup()` and
  `loop()`.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you very much for the explanation. The final code uses both timers so, I will avoid using the Arduino core in this case.